# Implement Themes in Activities- Changing Icons

Tags: android, imageview, themes

I'm trying to add theme capabilities to my app but have hit a roadblock when it comes to actually implementing themes into my activities.

Setting up the theme using styles and attributes is pretty simple, but the issue I've run into is changing all the app icons. The default theme is dark, so all my icons are white. I want to implement a white theme, though, and all of the icons need to change. Instead of applying a filter to every ImageView or replacing every Drawable, is it frowned upon to create multiple versions of each activity/layout file and inflate different views based on the theme chosen? Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out you can put integers in attr files, so I can supply different integers to the styles for drawables!

Implement like so:

```
        <attr name="reply" format="integer"/>
```

and in your styles

```
        <item name="ama">@drawable/amaenabled</item>
```

Cheers!